# More elegant way of handling this logic

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, logic

```
private bool SearchFilter(object sender)
{
    CommDGDataSource item = sender as CommDGDataSource;
    if (FilterPropertyList.IsErrorFilter)
    {
        if (!item.Error)
            return false;
    }
    if (FilterPropertyList.IsDestinationFilter)
    {
        if (!(item.Destination == FilterPropertyList.Destination))
            return false;
    }
    if (FilterPropertyList.IsSourceFilter)
    {
        if (!(item.Source == FilterPropertyList.Source))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Above code works well but I was wondering if there is more of an elegant way to write the above code.

Comment: I would only use `!` for atomic statements, in this case `!=` would save you the parentheses...

Comment: you could also use a switch statement for the outer if structure

Comment: Can the filter be more than one of the things at once? E.g. can it be an `ErrorFilter` and a `SourceFilter`?

Comment: @djery: using a `switch` would change the logic of the method.

Comment: Could you give more code for `FilterPropertyList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a bit more readable by making small alterations as below

```
private bool SearchFilter(object sender)
{
    CommDGDataSource item = sender as CommDGDataSource;

    if (FilterPropertyList.IsErrorFilter && !item.Error)
        return false;

    if (FilterPropertyList.IsDestinationFilter && item.Destination != FilterPropertyList.Destination)
        return false;

    if (FilterPropertyList.IsSourceFilter && item.Source != FilterPropertyList.Source)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Whether this is more readable or not depends on how wide your monitor is... but I think it should fit for most people.

Comment: This is probably what I would write. I know some people who prefer replacing the last `if` with a `return` instead of having the extra trailing `return`, but I prefer this as it makes modifying the filter later that little bit easier and clearer.

Comment: Only drawback is that you cannot paste any additional logic, if only first condition is true

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is much merit in messing with boolean expressions, except maybe for simple modifications as mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948956/more-elegant-way-of-handling-this-logic/11949374#comment15920040_11948956). If you end up with ugly code you have a design which just is not that great.

In this case you could probably refactor the responsibities by:

- Creating a list of filter *objects*
- Implementing the logic in those objects

Something like this Pseudocode:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
    if !filter.Filter(item) return false;
return true;
```

```
public interface IFilter
{
    bool Filter(CommDGDataSource item);
}

public class ErrorFilter : IFilter
{
    public bool Filter(CommDGDataSource item)
    {
        return item.Error;
    }
}

public class DestinationFilter : IFilter
{
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public bool Filter(CommDGDataSource item)
    {
        return item.Destination == Destination;
    }
}

//etc..
```